# MongoDB Aggregation using official C# driver?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm using the official C# driver.Have no idea to implement this:
    `Select MAX(TimeStamp) as MaxTimeStamp, ExtNo From AgentStatus Where TimeStamp>=@begin and TimeStamp <=@end Group By ExtNo`
Any Help?Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Already use MapReduce to solve the problerm :) A simple demo [HERE](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2012/03/19/a-simple-mapreduce-with-mongodb-and-c.aspx)