# How to implement this in MongoDB?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I migrated my SQL Server DataBase to MongoDB.Now I have a problerm.

```
select * from AgentStatus a,
(select Max(TimeStamp) as TimeStamp,ExtNo
from AgentStatus
group by Extno) b
where a.[TimeStamp] = b.[TimeStamp] and b.ExtNo = a.ExtNo
```

If we use RMDB,it's simple,but how to execute a query like this in MongoDB?Or I have to **change my schema**?And **How**?

Any help?Thanks!

Comment: I tried two single queries.After I executed the inner query,then iterated the result to **query the whole collection** with where clause "a.[TimeStamp] = b.[TimeStamp] and b.ExtNo = a.ExtNo".But the collection have **two million documents**,although i added indexes,it's still very **slow**.

Comment: What indexes have you created?

Comment: (Why did you migrate to MongoDB?)

Comment: @WiredPrairie Unique indexes, each for TimeStamp and ExtNo.<br>Original query is much more complex,this is a simplified edition,and my manager worried about its execution time.So we hope to use document database for a better performance.My english is poor,hope you could understand what I'm saying :)

Comment: Are you sure MongoDB was using the indexes you've created? Are you sure the "original" query isn't the problem (you said it's more complex, have you tested this case? Maybe it's your C# syntax? You'll need to post a bit more, as this is too speculative in its current state.

Comment: Yeah,pretty sure. There are 4 tables in the original query.But MongoDB doesn't support "Join",so I tried to **changed 4 tables to one collection**.So I get the simplified query now.May I ask you another question?If you have 2 collections with relationship and the "child "collection has many documents inside.How could you get the children **as soon as possilble** and also have good performance?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the aggregation framework.
Say you have a bunch of entries:

> db.a.find();

```
{ "_id" : 1, "n" : 1, "d" : ISODate("2012-01-01T00:00:00Z") } 
{ "_id" : 2, "n" : 1, "d" : ISODate("2012-01-12T00:00:00Z") }
{ "_id" : 3, "n" : 1, "d" : ISODate("2012-02-04T00:00:00Z") }
{ "_id" : 4, "n" : 2, "d" : ISODate("2012-01-22T00:00:00Z") }
{ "_id" : 5, "n" : 3, "d" : ISODate("2012-01-07T00:00:00Z") }
{ "_id" : 6, "n" : 2, "d" : ISODate("2011-12-31T00:00:00Z") }
```

You would then just group and max:

```
> db.a.aggregate({$group:{_id:"$n",latest:{$max:"$d"}}})
```

Which gives you a record for each n with the latest timestamp of that entry:

```
> db.a.aggregate({$group:{_id:"$n",latest:{$max:"$d"}}})
{
    "result" : [
            {
                    "_id" : 3,
                    "latest" : ISODate("2012-01-07T00:00:00Z")
            },
            {
                    "_id" : 2,
                    "latest" : ISODate("2012-01-22T00:00:00Z")
            },
            {
                    "_id" : 1,
                    "latest" : ISODate("2012-02-04T00:00:00Z")
            }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: Is this the answer of [my last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14917362/mongodb-aggregation-using-official-c-sharp-driver)?But still thanks! :)